# Send multiples messages in one request (webhook) in Teams

Tags: json, request, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to send multiple message card in same time

When I'm doing a request for only one message with postman, it works for example :

```
{
  "@type": "MessageCard",
  "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
  "summary": "Summary",
  "title": "Connector Card HTML formatting",
  "sections": [
    {
     "text": "This is some <strong>bold</strong> text"
    },
 }
```

And now, how can I create a another card message in same time?

Comment: Only a single message card works for me.

Comment: @Dev yes how can I send multiples messages card in one script ?

Comment: I really doubt we have an option to send multiple messages card. Unfortunately i failed to failed to see that in Microsoft Documentation either. Looks like by design to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Only a single message card works for me.
- I really doubt we have an option to send multiple messages card.
- Unfortunately i failed to failed to see that in Microsoft
  Documentation either.
- It looks like "by design" to me. It's confirmed
  above too.

Comment: thanks for your help, what do you mean by "by design" ?

Comment: So the best solution is to send multiples request ?

Comment: @zefzefaa By design means the API is designed to work in that way only. To answer your second question, yes, at this point you can't send multiple cards at a go; you can do it by sending multiple requests.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Webhook does not support sending multiple messages in one request. This is by  design.

Comment: thanks for your help, what do you mean "by design" ?

Comment: @Dev, is correct. By design means an incoming webhook is designed in a way through which you cannot send multiple cards at same time with one request.